# Does Response.Output in ASP.NET modifies the encoding of the files in the stream?

Tags: file, encoding, stream, response

In my **ASP.NET Web Forms** application, I have to let user download XML files. In order to do that, when they press the download button the following code is executed:

```
Response.Clear()
Response.CacheControl = "Private"
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(3))
Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")
Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}.xml", fileName))
Dim xmlFile As String = _xmlServices.GetXmlFile(fileId);

If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlFile) Then
    Dim xdoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
    xdoc.LoadXml(xmlFile)
    xdoc.Save(Response.Output)
End If

Response.Flush()
Response.End()
```

The `GetXmlFile(fileId)` function gives back a string containing the XML. The string obtained is already with the encoding specified (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`) and with signature. That means if the file is modified the signature is not valid anymore.

I use the same function `GetXmlFile(fileId)` for a **WPF application** and it works perfectly.

In my ASP.NET application however I have two problems:

1. If I do not explicitly specify `Response.ContentEncoding =
   Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")` the downloaded XML file has encoding `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`. This is not a big issue.
2. The XML file downloaded from the **ASP.NET application** has one carriage return character more than the file downloaded from the **WPF application**. The files might look identical to parse, since the carriage return appears at the end of a tag, without compromising the data. But the signature is not valid since the file has been changed after placing it.

Therefore I think somehow the `Response.Output` stream somehow modifies the files. Or there can be another reason behind this error?

Comment: Why not use Response.TransmitFile instead so that it's exactly the same as stored on your server

Comment: How can I use it in combination with an XmlDocument object?

Comment: Aha, sorry, I saw the call _licenseServices.GetXmlFile and thought it's actually a file on hard drive

Comment: no it is a file generated on the fly :-)